# How to return a value of a key from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Let me have a dictionary:

```
P={'S':['dB','N'],'B':['C','CcB','bA']}
```

How can I get second value o the second key from dictionary P ?

Also, if the value is a string with more than one character like 'bA' (third value of key 'B'), can I somehow return first character of this value ?

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: *"the second key"* is not a concept that makes sense - dictionaries are not ordered data structures. Lists and strings *are* ordered, and can both be indexed: `'bA'[0] == 'b'`, for example. Please review the basics: http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some example which you tried already and divide your question to two separate.

Comment: dictionary doesn't keep order - once `"B"` is second key but later it can be first key. You can use `list(P.keys())[1]` to get "second" key and later second value `P[ list(P.keys())[1] ][1]` and first char `P[ list(P.keys())[1] ][1][0]` (Python 3)

Answer (score 0):

Like @jonrsharpe has stated before, dictionaries aren't ordered by design.

What this means, is that everytime you attempt to access a dictionary "by order" you may encounter a different result.

Observe the following (python interactive interpreter):

```
>>>P={'S':['dB','N'],'B':['C','CcB','bA'], 'L':["qqq"]}
>>>P.keys()
['S', 'B', 'L']
```

Its easy to see that in this notice, the "order" as we defined is, matches the order that we receive from the Dictionary.keys() function.

However, you may also observe this result:

```
>>> P={'S':['dB','N'],'B':['C','CcB','bA'], 'L':["qqq"], 'A':[]}
>>> P.keys()
['A', 'S', 'B', 'L']
```

In this example, the value 'A' should be fourth in our list, but, it is actually the first value.

This is just a small example why you may not treat dictionaries as ordered lists.
Maybe you could go ahead and tell us what your intentions are and an alternative may be suggested.

Comment: Sorry for me being noobish, I'm kinda noob in python. I changed my goal and solved it.
`P={}
F={}
P={'S':['dB','N'],'B':['C','CcB']}
for key, val in P.items():
    for it in val:
        print(it[0])
        F.setdefault(key, [])
        F[key].append(it[0])        
        print(F)`